# Folding a list in F#

Tags: f#

I have a pretty trivial task but I can't figure out how to make the solution prettier.
The goal is taking a `List` and returning results, based on whether they passed a predicate. The results should be grouped. Here's a simplified example:

Predicate: `isEven`
`Inp : [2; 4; 3; 7; 6; 10; 4; 5]`
`Out:  [[^^^^]......[^^^^^^^^]..]`

Here's the code I have so far:

```
let f p ls =
    List.foldBack
        (fun el (xs, ys) -> if p el then (el::xs, ys) else ([], xs::ys))
        ls ([], [])
    |> List.Cons // (1)
    |> List.filter (not << List.isEmpty) // (2)

let even x = x % 2 = 0

let ret =
    [2; 4; 3; 7; 6; 10; 4; 5]
    |> f even
// expected [[2; 4]; [6; 10; 4]]
```

This code does not seem to be readable that much. Also, I don't like lines (1) and (2). Is there any better solution?

Comment: Your edit changes the question entirely. I suggest you rollback your edit, pick the best answer _to the original question_, and make your edit a separate question, if you still want community feedback on it.

Comment: @Daniel I feel you are correct when I'm looking at the answers. It seems everyone understood my question in a different way (than I understand it). This is, of course, my fault for not to stressing on readability first. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my take. you need a few helper functions first:

```
// active pattern to choose between even and odd intengers
let (|Even|Odd|) x = if (x % 2) = 0 then Even x else Odd x

// fold function to generate a state tupple of current values and accumulated values
let folder (current, result) x =
    match x, current with
    | Even x, _ -> x::current, result // even members a added to current list
    | Odd x, [] -> current, result    // odd members are ignored when current is empty
    | Odd x, _ -> [], current::result // odd members starts a new current

// test on data
[2; 4; 3; 7; 6; 10; 4; 5]
    |> List.rev                             // reverse list since numbers are added to start of current
    |> List.fold folder ([], [])            // perform fold over list
    |> function | [],x -> x | y,x -> y::x   // check that current is List.empty, otherwise add to result
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this one?

```
let folder p l = function
    | h::t when p(l) -> (l::h)::t
    | []::_ as a -> a
    | _ as a -> []::a

let f p ls =
    ls
    |> List.rev
    |> List.fold (fun a l -> folder p l a) [[]]
    |> List.filter ((<>) [])
```

At least the folder is crystal clear and effective, but then you pay the price for this by list reversing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive solution based on a recursive `List.filter`

```
let rec _f p ls =
    match ls with
    |h::t -> if p(h) then 
                 match  f p t with
                 |rh::rt -> (h::rh)::rt
                 |[] -> (h::[])::[]
             else []::f p t
    |[] -> [[]]

let  f p ls = _f p ls |> List.filter (fun t -> t <> [])
```

Having to filter at the end does seem inelegant though.

Comment: Hmm... Frankly, it does not look much better: `Cons` patterns may impact performance, and final filtering is essentially the same.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to do this elegantly using higher order functions, but here's a solution using a list comprehension. I think it's fairly straightforward to read.

```ml
let f p ls = 
  let rec loop xs = 
    [ match xs with 
      | [] -> ()
      | x::xs when p x -> 
        let group, rest = collectGroup [x] xs
        yield group
        yield! loop rest
      | _::xs -> yield! loop xs ]
  and collectGroup acc = function
    | x::xs when p x -> collectGroup (x::acc) xs
    | xs -> List.rev acc, xs
  loop ls
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. This function should also have fairly good performance.

```
let groupedFilter (predicate : 'T -> bool) (list : 'T list) =
    (([], []), list)
    ||> List.fold (fun (currentGroup, finishedGroups) el ->
        if predicate el then
            (el :: currentGroup), finishedGroups
        else
            match currentGroup with
            | [] ->
                [], finishedGroups
            | _ ->
                // This is the first non-matching element
                // following a matching element.
                // Finish processing the previous group then
                // add it to the finished groups list.
                [], ((List.rev currentGroup) :: finishedGroups))
    // Need to do a little clean-up after the fold.
    |> fun (currentGroup, finishedGroups) ->
        // If the current group is non-empty, finish it
        // and add it to the list of finished groups.
        let finishedGroups =
            match currentGroup with
            | [] -> finishedGroups
            | _ ->
                (List.rev currentGroup) :: finishedGroups

        // Reverse the finished groups list so the grouped
        // elements will be in their original order.
        List.rev finishedGroups;;
```

Comment: @svick -- Implement an imperative solution in C#. The code above is the functional equivalent of the most natural C# solution.

Answer (score 0):

With the list reversing, I would like to go to #seq instead of list.

This version uses mutation (gasp!) internally for efficiency, but may also be a little slower with the overhead of seq. I think it is quite readable though.

```
let f p (ls) = seq {
    let l = System.Collections.Generic.List<'a>()
    for el in ls do
      if p el then 
        l.Add el
      else 
        if l.Count > 0 then yield l |> List.ofSeq
        l.Clear()
    if l.Count > 0 then yield l |> List.ofSeq
   }
```

Comment: This won't yield the last group if the last item is a match.

Comment: @Daniel Right you are. Fixed it. That really made it uglier. :)

Comment: It's too bad. Although, it's still the most straightforward solution here.